# use of NOT EXIST in SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

In where clause what is the exact meaning of following NOT EXIST please help me to understand.

```
WHERE
        NOT EXISTS  
        (
            SELECT
                'z'
            FROM
                Mytemptable
            WHERE
                Mytemptable.Date = @PositionDate AND
                Mytemptable.PurchaseLotId = PurchaseTable.PurchaseLotId
        )
```

Comment: Could you post the first part of query please?

Comment: `WHERE [NOT] <Does this query returns any records?>` => `WHERE <This query returns no records>`

Comment: The bit in parentheses is a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) - PurchaseTable must be referenced in the outer query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relational operator in question is semi difference a.k.a. [antijoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_.28.E2.8B.89.29.28.E2.8B.8A.29). Most SQL products lack an explicit semi difference operator or keyword and using `NOT EXISTS` is one of many workarounds. Note the text literal `z` could be replaced with any valid literal, column or `*` with no change in behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It specifies that there are no results from the nested sub query, i.e., only rows that do not yield any results in the sub query will be included in the result of the super query.

Answer (score 1):

[[NOT] EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) tests for the existence of rows.  In your query, that `select` statement will either return rows or return nothing (`NULL`).  If your query doesn't return rows, then whatever is prior to your `WHERE` clause will be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

NOT EXISTS  means nothing returned by sub query. 
EXISTS as opposite means "one or more rows returned by subquery"

```
SELECT * FROM Users as Homeless WHERE NOT EXISTS 
         (SELECT * FROM Addresses WHERE Addresses.userId = Users.userId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, it checks that there are no records on your temptable for the specified @date value, that match the PurchaseTable.PurchaseLotId value from the main query. (The use of a 'z' is irrelevant, since it is merely testing for existence.)